# The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble whilst following a beginner android dev program.

I am making a sort of contacts manager, and I am trying to implement right now a way to call contacts.

However since adding the callButton I have had this error on the line below my first Button, this:

*button.setOnClickListener(new public void OnClick(View v){Listener() {"*

I don't really understand the error so any help would be great thanks.

```
    public class ContactPickerTester extends Activity {
    public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_picker_tester);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        button.setOnClickListener(new public void OnClick(View v){Listener() {


            public void onClick(View _view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri
                        .parse("content://contacts/"));
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);




        Button insertContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        insertContactButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insertContactWithIntent();
            }
        });
    }


    private void insertContactWithIntent() {
        //inserting a new contact using intents//
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(intent);



 Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

 callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
         startActivity(myIntent);
     }
 });
 }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT): {
            if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_contact_textview);
                tv.setText(name);
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for creating an anonymous inner class is a little mixed up. That line should be:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View _view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri
                    .parse("content://contacts/"));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
});
```

Comment: now to work out why the third button does nothing when I press it! Agh. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3466400 - Use the debugger to check whether your listener is being called when you press it. The nesting levels of your code look a little tangled up (and I don't know how they ended up after you made the fix I suggested), but make sure you are actually assigning a listener to the third button in `onCreate()`.